# BottomAppBarr change color of notched shape

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to change the color of this part?

[image]

My bottom bar is here:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      elevation: 8,
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: changePage,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(backgroundColor: Colors.orange, icon: Icon(Icons.view_day), activeIcon: Icon(Icons.view_day, color: Colors.orange,), title: Text("Home")),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(backgroundColor: Colors.orange, icon: Icon(Icons.settings), activeIcon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.orange,), title: Text("Settings"))],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is Scaffold background color

Answer (score 1):

Make extendBody: true in Scaffold

```
Scaffold(
extendBody: true,
body: body(),
bottomNavigationBar: bottomAppBar(),
)
```